# Why won't this array property populate

Tags: arrays, powershell, scripting

I have two multidimensional arrays that have some shared data.  The elements are not in the same order between the two arrays, nor do the property names match in every instance.  However, the fields to compare will always have the same name (i.e. $Asset in Array1 and $Name in $Array2).  What I want is for the a property in Array1 to be populated when there is a partial match in Array2.  Below is an example.

```
$Array1 = @(
    @{Asset = '123'; Region = 'Earth'; User = ''}
    @{Asset = '098'; Region = 'Moon'; User = 'Carla'}
    )


$Array2 = @(
    @{Name= '123456'; User = 'Steve'; Date = '1/1/22'}
    )
```

What I would like is for the script to find the partial match (123) and, based on that, populate $Array1.user with "Steve".  It seems like this should be an easy thing to do with a ForEach loop, but I cannot work out how to do it.  Below are some samples of things I've tried.

```
ForEach ($Comp in $Array1)
{
    $Array2 -like "*$Comp*"
    $Comp.user = ($Array2).user
  }

_______________

ForEach ($Comp in $Array1)
{
     $Comp -match $Array2
     $Comp.user = $($Array2).user
}
```

I have tried different combinations of nested ForEach loops, ForEach loops with If statements, etc.  I'm sure this is an easy fix, but I am new to PS and am not seeing my problem.  Could you please help?  It's the only thing keeping my script from being complete.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You don't "populate properties" on arrays, you fill them with other objects. Perhaps you want an array of hashtables instead? eg. `$array1 = @{Asset = '123'; Region = 'Earth'; User = $null},@{Asset = '098'; Region = 'Moon'; User = 'Carla'}`

Comment: Thanks for responding @MathiasR.Jessen.  Apologies for the incorrect terminology.  I think you get my meaning, though.  I just need to modify the property value when a certain condition is met.

I had thought about using a hash table, though not an array of them.  Since everything else in the script is working except for this one detail, I would prefer to stick to the original plan.  Do you have any idea how to get that to work?

Comment: Your sample code for $array1 and $array2 isn’t valid Powershell - if you cut and paste from your question into a PowerShell console you get syntax errors. Could you review and update the code?

Comment: @mclayton - Not sure why I entered it the way I did.  I have corrected it in the original post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to clarify some terminology first, you've **not** actually got multidimensional arrays - you'd declare those with something like `$x = new-object "string[,]" 2, 2` and then you'd have to poke each value into the array individually to initialise it with `$x[0, 0] = "aaa"; $x[0, 1] = "bbb"; ... etc`

What you've **really** got is two single-dimension arrays where each item in the array is a hashtable.

Having said that, a simple way to do what you want is with this imperative snippet:

```
# set up some test data
$Array1 = @(
    @{ "Asset" = "123"; "Region" = "Earth"; "User" = "" },
    @{ "Asset" = "098"; "Region" = "Moon";  "User" = "Carla"}
)
$Array2 = @(
    @{ "Name" = "123456"; "User" = "Steve"; "Date" = "010/1/22" }
)

# update the user details
foreach( $item1 in $Array1 )
{
    foreach( $item2 in $Array2 )
    {
        if( $item2.Name -like "$($item1.Asset)*" )
        {
            $item1.User = $item2.User
        }
    }
}

# show the result
$Array1 | ConvertTo-Json
# [
#   {
#     "Region": "Earth",
#     "User": "Steve",     # <-- was "", is now "Steve"
#     "Asset": "123"
#   },
#   {
#     "Region": "Moon",
#     "User": "Carla",
#     "Asset": "098"
#   }
# ]
```

The nested `foreach` loops basically compare every item in `$Array1` with every item in `$Array2` and update the item from `$Array1` when the `if` expression is true.

There's probably some slightly slicker approaches with a pipeline, but the code above gets the job done :-).

Comment: Thank you for correcting me @mclayton.  I am quite the neophyte.  I tried your code and I did not get the results you posted.  In my experience (copy/pasting your code), the User was changed to Steve in both.

Comment: @Slonky - i've added some setup code for the test data - try it again now and see if you get the same results...

Comment: This is a work project, so I will look at it again tomorrow and let you know.

Comment: I can't tell you how much I appreciate your help.  That gave me the last piece that I needed for my script.  Again, Thank You!